module 'motion' has no attribute 'motden'
I have two souce code which I have downloaded from a research paper (free).
The link for two source code is: named as main_2, source_2
When I run the source_2 code every time it shows :main_2.py", line 63, in 
   track, t = source_2.math_dxdydz (x, y, z, U, Q, R, O, P, H, C, G, M, A, B, W, S, I,α, β, τ, γ, λ, θ, ρ, L, length, densy)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\Math\Research\Game in Supply chain\New\New folder\1-s2.0-S0360835222002029-mmc1\1-s2.0-S0360835222002029-mmc1\ESS comparison analysis\000\source_2.py", line 26, in math_dxdydz
    track = motion.motden(function, x, y, z, t, U, Q, R, O, P, H, C, G, M, A, B, W, S, I,α, β, τ, γ, λ, θ, ρ, L)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'motion' has no attribute 'motden'. Did you mean: 'motion'?

I have deleted the motion.pyc file, but it didn't help.
What is motdin?
Was it used in previous Python version? I have also tried older version Python it says bad magic number.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That looks like a type error. Try motion.motion instead of motion.motdin

From the library's homepage https://pypi.org/project/motion/, it looks like the correct name should be "Motion," with a capital letter. So, motion.Motion.
